# Stop Android BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver

I'm using BroadcastReceiver class in android to get information about network change

using the following code:

```
 class NetworkStatus extends BroadcastReceiver{    
    ......
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
}
       public void startBroadCastReceiver()
{

}

public void  StopBroadCastReceiver()
{
}
```

I want to stop the broadcast receiver and then start it again 
How can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast receiver likes event handler, Android system calls it automatically when a broadcast matches you defined intent. If you define the boardcast receiver in manifast file, I think the only way you can do it to return immediately when you don't want to handle the broadcast, like the following:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if (stoppedBroadcast)
          return;

     // handle broadcast.
}

public void stopBroadcast {
     stoppedBroadcast = true;
}

public void resumeBroadcast {
     stoppedBroadcast = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop recieving network changes try [unregisterReciever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29) in your registering activity/service.
When you want to enable recieving register the reciever with its IntentFilter again.